# How to take a screenshot of a something bigger than the screen?

Tags: screenshot, screen-capture

I have a created a route using Google Maps. I want to take a screenshot of this route in satellite view with maximum zoom. But since it doesn't fit my screen I can't do it. It there a way around this?

Comment: A screen shot, by definition, is a shot of the screen. Question should probably read: How to **Save _entire_ Page As Image** regardless of the browser window size, which is pretty much built-in in Firefox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get bigger images from Google Maps, you need to use **[Google Map Saver](http://www.codres.de/google-map-saver)**.

Google Map Saver (GMS) offers you an easy and free way to download big Google Maps on your PC as JPEG, PNG-8, PNG-24, BMP or Targa files. GMS is light (only ~400 KBytes) and very easy to run since doesn’t have an installer. You can save maps up to 12000 x 12000 pixels!

[image]

Comment: +1: Much better than my solution.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but this application doesn't seem to do what I want. It allows me to zoom to a certain level, and then take a high resolution screenshot of currently the visible portion of the map. Taking a screenshot of the entire route at max zoom level doesn't work because the map is much bigger than the application screen.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. The program gives you the options to play with resolution and zoom. Normally you can't do this without the help of a program. Application screen shouldn't matter in this case...

Comment: Ok, my mistake. It seems that I had to press the GO! button *after* choosing the right resolution. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: There is now a [Firefox built-in solution](https://superuser.com/a/1198900/717673) for all websites (not limited to Google Maps)

Answer (score 5):

### Any Website, Any Size.

Use a combination of Firefox, Developer tools, Responsive Design Mode, and Screenshot, all available without extra software or add-ons:

[image: Firefox, Developer tools, Responsive Design Mode, and Screenshot]

Tested on Firefox 52.x, probably works in earlier versions.

You can of course also leverage add-ons as outlined in [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1198900/717673).

Works on *any* website which would normally limit the viewing area to your window size, as shown on this very large Sky picture:

[image: Google Sky]

Image source: https://www.google.com/sky/ (i.e. not Google Map) at **5401×3603** pixels and **8.9** MB

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Firefox, the [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/) extension should do the job - it can capture just what's visible OR the entire page depending on what you want.

[image]

Comment: There's also [ScreenGrab https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146/]

Comment: One problem is that the Google Maps application intelligently resizes the map area to fit within the border of the browser window. However, I noticed that I can wrap it in an iframe that exceeds window borders. I'll try it today after work.

Comment: These add-ons are merely answering the question «**How to take a screen shot**», not «**...something bigger than the screen**». To make web screen grab bigger than life, see [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1198900/717673).

Answer (score 0):

If you expand the window to as large as you want (even if it goes off the screen) you can press alt+prtsc to take a print screen of that application.

Comment: In Windows XP, Alt+Print Screen will only capture the visible part of the window. The captured image is cut off at the edge of the screen.

Comment: @Bqvi_H, also it only captures within the window borders.

Comment: It's not really the window that is the physical limit, it is it's rendering space (how much the webpage real estate is available). Tell the webpage that it has more space **+** capture that entire space **=** take a screen grab bigger than the screen. See [superuser.com/questions/1198899](https://superuser.com/a/1198900/717673).